# Failed to run homestead vagrant box

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm trying to install the Laravel Homestead vagrant box. I followed the [official documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead) and when I run `vagrant up` I get this error:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "/Users/carlo/.vagrant.d/boxes/laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead/0.2.7/virtualbox/box.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "settler_default_1434987271004_24349_1442413617944_69497", "--vsys", "0", "--unit", "7", "--disk", "/Users/carlo/VirtualBox VMs/settler_default_1434987271004_24349_1442413617944_69497/box-disk1.vmdk"]

Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting /Users/carlo/.vagrant.d/boxes/laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead/0.2.7/virtualbox/box.ovf...
OK.
0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
VBoxManage: error: Appliance import failed
VBoxManage: error: Could not create the imported medium '/Users/carlo/VirtualBox VMs/settler_default_1434987271004_24349_1442413617944_69497/box-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_VD_VMDK_INVALID_FORMAT)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component ApplianceWrap, interface IAppliance
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleImportAppliance(HandlerArg*)" at line 876 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

I tried vagrant with another simple ubuntu box and it's working

Comment: Could you please verify that the file `/Users/carlo/.vagrant.d/boxes/laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead/0.2.7/virtualbox/box.ovf` exists?

Comment: Yes it does. It's a long xml file

Comment: looks like the box is corrupted, remove the box from vagrant list (`vagrant box remove laravel/homestead`) and download it again

Comment: removing and reinstalling actually worked. How did it get corrupted in the first place, though? I downloaded it just the day before and did nothing on it. Anyway thanks